# Find sum of elements of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $A=[a_{ij}]$ is $10\times10$ matrix which satisfies :

A) $\left\{a_{ij}|1\le i, j\le 10\right\}= \left\{1, 2, \cdots, 100\right\}$

B) For $p, q\in\mathbb{N} | 1\le p, q\le 10$, $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{ip}=\sum_{j=1}^{10}a_{qj}$

C) $\det(A)\neq 0$

Find sum of elements of $A^{-1}$.

---

**My Attempt :**

From condition C, $A^{-1}$ exists.

And from condition A, B, for each row (or column) of $A$, sum of elements of itself is $505$ because $\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\sum_{n=1}^{100}n = 505$.

What should I do to find sum of elements of $A^{-1}$? I don't know how should I use these informations, Thank you.

Comment: your statement that each for of $A$ has a sum of 505 means that you have an eigenvector equation $A\mathbf 1 = \lambda \mathbf 1$ (using the ones vector).  This means $A^{-1}\mathbf 1 = \lambda^{-1}\mathbf 1$ so the sum is  $\mathbf 1^T A^{-1}\mathbf 1 = \lambda^{-1}\mathbf 1^T\mathbf 1 = \lambda^{-1}\cdot 10$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B = [b_{ij}]$ be the inverse matrix. By definition,

$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10} a_{ik} b_{kj} = \delta_{ij}
$$

Let's sum it up for $i$ from $1$ to $10$:

$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{10} a_{ik} b_{kj} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{10} b_{kj} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} a_{ik}= 1.
$$

But $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} a_{ik} = 505$, hence

$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10} b_{kj} = \frac{1}{505}.
$$

Summing it up for all $j$, we get that the sum of all elements is $\frac{10}{505}$.

Comment: I am wondering whether this could be explained using [Sinkhorn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinkhorn%27s_theorem)